# Remove domain group for Local Administrators using wild card

Tags: powershell

I am trying to clean up the local administrators group on some machines and need a solution in Powershell. So far I've managed to retrieve the list of members but I'm having trouble with my syntax to find the group I want to remove. The group on each machine that needs removal will be different but does have the same name format.

I could use this if the group name was the same:

```
$objGroup = [ADSI]("WinNT://$Env:COMPUTERNAME/Administrators")
$objGroupMembers = $objGroup.psbase.Invoke("Members") | foreach {$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty',$null, $_, $null)}
$objRemoveGroup = [ADSI]("WinNT://Contoso/ABC-MyAdmins")
$objGroup.PSBase.Invoke("Remove",$objRemoveGroup.PSBase.Path)
```

But the groups I need to remove will be removing could be named XYZ-MyAdmins or ABC-XYZ-MyAdmins. Basically I just want to remove any member of the Local Administrators group that is like *-MyAdmins.

So if I do something like this, it doesn't work:

```
$objGroup = [ADSI]("WinNT://$Env:COMPUTERNAME/Administrators")
$objGroupMembers = $objGroup.psbase.Invoke("Members") | foreach {$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty',$null, $_, $null)}
$ObjRemove = ForEach($Member in ($objGroupMembers | Where-Object {$Member -like '*-MyAdmins'}))
{
$objRemoveGroup = [ADSI]("WinNT://Contoso/$($ObjRemove)")
$objGroup.PSBase.Invoke("Remove",$objRemoveGroup.PSBase.Path)
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I just needed to post a question in order to figure this out on my own. I'd still like to know what is broken with my original code though so if someone has the time to take a look I'd appreciate it. I'm still learning the ins and outs of PowerShell.

This is working as needed:

```
 $objGroup = [ADSI]("WinNT://$Env:COMPUTERNAME/Administrators")
 $objGroupMembers = $objGroup.psbase.Invoke("Members") | foreach {$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty',$null, $_, $null)}
        ForEach($Member in $objGroupMembers)
        {
            If($Member -like "*-MyAdmins")
            {$objRemoveGroup = [ADSI]("WinNT://Contoso/$($Member)")
             $objGroup.PSBase.Invoke("Remove",$objRemoveGroup.PSBase.Path)}
        }
```